# How to detect the location, scale and rotation of an object in a scene?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect the location, scale and rotation of an object in a scene. I used cvMatchTemplate function to dectect the object and it worked. How can I detect the location, scale and rotation of that object?

Answer (score 0):

cvMatchTemplate will only find translation. If you want to find also scale and rotation, I suggest you to use [Features2D + Homography](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)

Answer (score 0):

Location, scale and *in-plane* rotation sounds like Similarity transformation. Unlike Homography (which is more general and involves a non-linear operation - division), similarity transformation can be solved in closed form and thus doesn’t require non-linear optimization.

First you need to select correspondent points either by hand or through matching them with some kind of descriptor that is scale/rotation invariant;

After you selected min 2 correspondences with the coordinates put in columns of A and B matrices, use these formulas to find desired parameters:

**rotation: R = VU<sup>T</sup> where , where SVD of BA<sup>T</sup> = ULV<sup>T</sup>

scale: s =  sum[(a<sub>i</sub> - mean_a)<sup>T</sup>*R*(b<sub>i</sub> - mean_b)] / sum[(b<sub>i</sub> - mean_b)<sup>T</sup>(b<sub>i</sub> - mean_b)]

translation: T = sum(a<sub>i</sub> - s*R*b<sub>i</sub>)/N, where N is the number of correspondences**

If you have outliers in your data you have to use [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) to make your calculation robust.
Alternative way to fins matches when you have a lot of well defined points is [geometric hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_hashing). It doesn’t require descriptors or known matching (correspondences).